# Scilab xcos integrator

Tags: scilab, xcos

I have been facing a problem how to generate event signals based on value at the integrator block in Scilab Xcos. For example I need to create event signal in case value at the output of the integrator block is equal to zero. I had an idea to use the RELATIONALOP block for the comparison of the value at the output of the integrator with zero but I don´t know how to convert result of this comparison into the event. Can anybody help?

Comment: The best place for asking this question is the scilab users mailing list : http://lists.scilab.org/mailman/listinfo/users

Comment: Thank you, Stéphane Mottelet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zcross_f, NEGTOPOS_f POSTONEg_f AND general_F  blockS  are exactly designed for this purpose.

There based on the zero-crossing ability of ODE/DAE solver the continuous time integration is performed till a given expression of the states exactly crosses zero. At this time the discret simulation handles the immediate consequences of this events before the continuous state integration restarts.